# Get number of rows in Laravel's Eloquent before using "take" and "skip"

Tags: php, laravel, count, eloquent

I want to query my Laravel model using eloquent for results that may need to match some where clauses, then `take` and `skip` predefined numbers.

This isn't a problem in itself, but I also need to know the number of rows that were found in the query before reducing the result set with take and skip - so the original number of matches which could be every row in the table if no where clauses are used or a few if either is used.

What I want to do could be accomplished by making the query twice, with the first omitting "`->take($iDisplayLength)->skip($iDisplayStart)`" at the end and counting that, but that just seems messy.

Any thoughts?

```
$contacts = Contact::where(function($query) use ($request)
{

    if (!empty($request['firstname'])) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('firstname', 'LIKE', "%{$request['firstname']}%");

        });
    }   

    if (!empty($request['lastname'])) {
        $query->where(function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('lastname', 'LIKE', "%{$request['lastname']}%");

        });
    }     

})
->take($iDisplayLength)->skip($iDisplayStart)->get();

$iTotalRecords = count($contacts);
```

Comment: Just call `count` and `take()->skip()->get()`, what's messy about it?

Comment: How do you mean sorry? Surely I'd have to repeat the whole -- $contacts = Contact::where(function($query) use ($request) .... -- part each time?

Comment: No, you don't. Check my answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `count` then `get` on the same query.

And by the way, your whole query is a bit over complicated. It results in something like this:

```
select * from `contacts` where ((`firstname` like ?) and (`lastname` like ?)) limit X, Y
```

Closure in `where` is used to make a query like this for example:

```
select * from table where (X or Y) and (A or B);
```

So to sum up you need this:

```
$query = Contact::query();

if (!empty($request['firstname'])) {
  $query->where('firstname', 'like', "%{$request['firstname']}%");
}

if (!empty($request['lastname'])) {
  $query->where('lastname', 'like', "%{$request['lastname']}%");
}

$count = $query->count();

$contacts = $query->take($iDisplayLength)->skip(iDisplayStart)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out too. I used $query =  DB::table('contacts'); however, and everything else the same.

Comment: However result is completely different. You end up with array of stdObjects instead of Eloquent Collection.

Comment: `$query->count` returns the wrong result in many of my cases... might be because of joins or anything, but it is definitely not the way to go unfortunately...

Answer (score 3):

The `Collection` class offers a splice and a count method which you can take advantage of.

First you would want to get the collection..

```
$collection = $query->get();
```

Then you can get the count and splice it.

```
$count = $collection->count();
$records = $collection->splice($iDisplayStart, $iDisplayLength);
```

This might be hard on performance because you are querying for the entire collection each time rather than putting a limit on the query, so it might be beneficial to cache the collection if this page is going to be hit often.  At the same time though, this will hit the database only once, so it's a bit of a trade off.

Comment: The post above is much more efficient since it only pulls in the needed results from SQL.  It does result in two sql queries (one for count and one to get the results), but that's better than pulling in unneeded results.

Comment: If it's an expensive query that isn't returning a lot of results, it would be faster to allow PHP to handle it.  Also if you are using two queries, there is potential to get wrong information if there are insert/update/delete statements also running.  Both solutions should be considered depending on the use case.